# Is it possible to set watchpoint in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

Is it possible to set watchpoint in vscode?

It has not been supported by 2018\11(i.e https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/55931). Does it work now?

Comment: you can issue gbd commands from VSC, so you can set the watchpoint if needed

Comment: Yes, but it's not convenient.